# Lag in Sticky keys for mac?

Tags: mac, keyboard

I enabled sticky keys on my mac by going to system preferences,accessibility,enable sticky keys, and I really enjoy this sticky keys function, but there is a very small lag that is noticeable when I am typing really fast.

Basically, if you press any key (say the <kbd>space</kbd> bar for example) and then press <kbd>shift</kbd> right afterwards immediately, the sticky keys is disabled and the next key you press will not be capitalized.

I recommend you try this because it is very interesting. The only reason it really is a big issue for me is because I speed type on typeracer.com. This is a website where you can increase your typing speed. When you are typing 100+ words per minute many times the sticky keys will not work to capitalize your next character because you are typing so fast and this results in a mistake and a vastly lower typing score. (the reason I don't use shift is because when typing fast shift is hard to time and results in more mistakes which results in worse words per minute score).

Is there any program I can download or any command I can enter in terminal in order to fix this very small lag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce the delay with an Apple Wireless Keyboard. I wasn't sure about it at first, but you only have to press shift immediately after space, and the next key won't be sticky.

[KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/) has its own implementation for sticky keys that doesn't seem to have that issue.

[image]